# How to translate Kotlin Nothing to Java?

Tags: java, kotlin, generics, kotlin-java-interop

I have a class that is `MyClass<T>`

I need to subclass it to `MySubclass<Nothing>`

But sometimes I need to send a `MyClass` reference to a Java function, which in turn can receive `MySubclass`, How can I declare it so that it is compatible?

Or should I simply use `void receiveClass(aClass: MyClass<*>)` ?

Comment: If the second version works, it sounds ideal.

Comment: @LouisWasserman well it isn't ideal because it will be able to receive any type and not only the ones that have Nothing

Comment: There isn't really a solution that will solve that problem, as `Nothing` doesn't exist in Java.

Comment: Yeah i Will probably just use Void instead of Nothing to avoid compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can do:

```kotlin
// Kotlin:
open class MyClass<T>
class MySubclass : MyClass<Nothing>()
```

```java
// Java:
static <E> void receiveClass(MyClass<E> c) {
}

static void receiveClass1(MyClass<?> c) {
}
```

```kotlin
// Kotlin:
@JvmStatic
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  receiveClass(MySubclass())
  receiveClass1(MySubclass())
}
```

Both variants will work and are equivalent during runtime, the difference is whether you need the type information `<E>` inside the `receiveClass` for type safety in compile time.